# Is there a reason for two tags: [same-origin-policy] [allow-same-origin]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently, there are two tags on SO:

[same-origin-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/same-origin-policy) (697 questions) and
[allow-same-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/allow-same-origin) (31 questions)

*(I'm a meta-noob, so I don't know the proper process here...)*

Comment: I think that and [tag:cross-domain] should be synonymed to [tag:same-origin-policy]. Do a search for access-control-allow-origin and there is around 15,000 questions with various forms of tagging that should all be tagged [tag:same-origin-policy]

Comment: Yeah, virtually all the [tag:allow-same-origin] questions seem to just be about the same origin policy and so could better have been tagged with [tag:same-origin-policy] to begin with. `allow-same-origin` is literally just one of the allowed values for the `sandbox` attribute of the HTML `iframe` element — but none of the questions tagged with [tag:allow-same-origin] actually seem to be about that value of the `sandbox` attribute.